# Populate categories in custom backend configuration field

Tags: magento-1.9

I can populate the options on the multiselect like this in image below
[image]
in my system.xml

```
                .....  
                <custom_field_four>
                        <label>Custom Multiselect Field</label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>customconfig/options</source_model>
                        <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Example of multiselect field.</comment>
                    </custom_field_four>
                   .....
```

And as according to source model, in the file  `app/code/local/Mycorp/CustomConfig/Model/Options.php` loading options

```
<?php
  class Mycorp_CustomConfig_Model_Options{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
      return array(
        array('value'=>1, 'label'=>'One'),
        array('value'=>2, 'label'=>'Two'),
        array('value'=>3, 'label'=>'Three'),            
        array('value'=>4, 'label'=>'Four')                     
      );
    }
  }
```

Now instead of loading these dummy options i need to populate all categories(Both used and not used in navigation) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
  class Mycorp_CustomConfig_Model_Options{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
      $categories  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name') ;  
      $result = array();
      foreach($categories as $_category) {
        $result[] = array('value'=>$_category->getId(), 'label'=>$_category->getName());  
      }
      return $result;
    }
  }
```

Comment: No label is being printed, it's all blank

Comment: @K.C. added addAttributeToSelect('name')

Comment: OR you can use class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Category
as source_model

Answer (score 1):

On **Mycorp_CustomConfig_Model_Options** class at  **toOptionArray()** function **you need to call Category Collection model** .

then return in ***options  format***.So add below code at there.

```
$collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$catgories=$collection->load()->toArray(array('entity_id','name'));
    $Array = array();
      foreach($catgories as $_category) {
        $Array[] = array('value'=>$_category['entity_id'], 'label'=>$_category['name']);  
      }

     return $Array;
```

**Note:**

Here i use `toArray()` for getting data in array with `specific fields` ***entity_id,name***